# let binding with projectile-project-root binds to nil

Tags: elisp, let, emacs-projectile

I think I'm missing something but why, in the following function, `root` value is `nil`?

```lisp
(defun test-root ()
  (let (root (projectile-project-root))
    (message "root: %s\nprojectile: %S" root (projectile-project-root)
```

This is the result of my evaluation:

```
root: nil
projectile: "/home/lhooq/test_let/
```

Answer (score 1):

Because I forgot parentheses...

The correct function is:

```lisp
(defun test-root ()
  (let ((root (projectile-project-root)))
    (message "root: %s\nprojectile: %S" root (projectile-project-root)
```